# Normalize input with equal length streams

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I use ffmpeg to take an arbitrary input file and have the output make audio and video streams equal length starting at time 0.  The audio padded with silence.  And the video repeating the first frame on the beginning and the last frame on the end.

Edited for clarity:

If the video content starts after the sound, I would like to take the first frame and show it from 0 until the video starts.

If the video content stops before the sound, I would like to take the last frame of the video and display it until the audio stops.

If the audio starts after the video, I would like to pad the gap with silence.  If the audio stops before the video, I would like to pad the gap with silence.

Comment: "*And the video repeating the first frame on the beginning and the last frame on the end."* I don't understand this requirement. Why beginning **and** end? How do you know how long to repeat begin and end? Do both begin and end have the same duration of repeat or do they vary?

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear.  I have worked around and scripted this with another library but it would be nice to know how to do it with ffmpeg too

Comment: This is all possible with ffmpeg, but how do you know when the video and audio start in relation to each other?

Comment: Using the metadata from ffprobe for start times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pad video

With the [tpad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tpad) filter.

Pad beginning:

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -vf "tpad=start_duration=3:start_mode=clone" -c:a copy output
```

Pad end:

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -vf "tpad=stop_duration=10:start_mode=clone" -c:a copy output
```

## Pad audio

Pad beginning with the [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -af "adelay=delays=3s:all=1" -c:v copy output
```

Pad end with the [apad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#apad) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -af apad -c:v copy -shortest output
```